# Join dataframe with different indices

Tags: python, join, pandas, dataframe, indices

please consider the following dataframe with daily dates as its index

```
    df1= pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

now I have a second dataframe df2 where df2.index is a subset of df1.index
I want to join the data from df2 into df1 and for the missing indices I want to have NAN.
In a second step I want to replace the NaN with the last available data like this:

```
 2004-03-28 5
 2004-03-30 NaN
 2004-03-31 NaN
 2004-04-01 7
```

should become

```
 2004-03-28 5
 2004-03-30 5
 2004-03-31 5
 2004-04-01 7
```

many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have common index and just a single column that is named the same in both dataframes:

First merge

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

Now fill the missing values using 'ffill' which means [forwards fill](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1 = df1.fillna(method='ffill')
```

In the situation where the columns are not named the same you can either rename the columns:

```
right.rename(columnss={'old_name':'new_name'},inplace=True)
```

or specify the columns from both left and right hand side to merge with:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='left_col', right='right_col', how='left')
```

if the indexes don't match then you have to set `left_index=False` and `right_index=False`